# Write data to microchip rn4870 vie ble

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, microchip

I am working with microchip rn4780.
I succeed to connect to the device, but when I try to send it data (2 bytes),
I don't get a response (It should run some motor).
I think the problem is the characteristic I am working with, But I am not sure.
This is my code

```
override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status)
        for (service in gatt!!.services){
            Log.d(TAG, "Service: " + service.uuid.toString())
            for (char in service.characteristics) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Char: " + char.uuid.toString())
                if(char.uuid.toString() == "49535343-8841-43f4-a8d4-ecbe34729bb3") {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Try to write")
                    char.value = byteArrayOf(0x39, 0x31)
                    gatt!!.writeCharacteristic(char)
                    Log.d(TAG, "Finish to write")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to work with other apps from google play, but only one worked, it calls "lightblue".
[From that screen, it worked perfect (I send 39 and then 31 in hex)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNzt0.jpg)
[From that screen it doesn't work, for each characteristic, I have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lIrH.jpg)

There is a guide of microchip but i dont understand what they are doing different: 
https://microchipdeveloper.com/wireless:ble-mchp-transparent-uart-service

By the way, I tried it with flutter and it didn't work too, so if there is a solution for flutter it will be better.

Comment: Note that you may only have one outstanding GATT operation. Wait for callback until you execute the next one.

Comment: I am doing only one operation, First I wait it will connect, then I wait till I get the services I am doing only one operation, First I wait it will connect, then I wait till I get the services and then just run over them and write to some characteristic. There is something I am missing?

Comment: If there are multiple characteristics with that uuid, you will do multiple writes before completion of the first, with that code.

Comment: There is only one characteristic with that uuid

Comment: You could try Write Without Response as write type?

Comment: It doesn't work too. 
There is a guide off microchip:
https://microchipdeveloper.com/wireless:ble-mchp-transparent-uart-service
Maybe it helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, what I used the microchip page on the app, it sends some bytes before and after my massage.
I figure it out by looking at the Log file on the app.

Comment: What do you mean by "what I used the microchip page on the app" ? PS.: If this solved your problem please indicate your answer as accepted.

Comment: I sent the message I needed from that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNzt0.jpg screen, and then I looked at the log file and saw that the app added some bytes to my commend.